# "nuts" and "on one's chin"

Tags: american-english, slang, jokes

So I am enjoying this sketch [**That One Guy Who Still Says “These Nuts”**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxyiccilVKM&t=5s) (from the U.S, only available in some countries),

What does "these nuts on your chin" mean when Vince says from 1:10～?

> I was worried about **these nuts on your chin**.

Googling  "on one's chin" doesn't produce anything but "take something on one's chin".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Nuts" is slang for "testicles". He's corrupting everyone's speech to say he's putting his testicles on their chin. It's immature humor.

> [nuts](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nuts)
> noun [ plural ]
> offensive for testicle
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

Notice that the colleague (Key) is serious and concerned about the behavior of Vince (Peele), but Vince responds in an unexpected, immature way:

> Colleague: Vince, I'm worried about you.
> Vince: ... I was worried about these nuts on your chin.
> Colleague: Vince, seriously.
> Vince: These nuts were seriously on your chin.

"These nuts", often spoken as "**deez** nuts", was a fairly popular punchline for immature jokes a few years ago. There's even an entry on [knowyourmeme.com](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/deez-nuts):

> About
>
> Deez Nuts is the punchline of a conversational joke that involves asking someone a vaguely-phrased question to solicit a follow-up question in response, typically in the form of one of the five Ws, before yelling out the said phrase in an obnoxious manner. While originally introduced as a skit track on Dr. Dre's 1992 rap album Chronic, the joke saw a huge resurgence after it was featured in a short comedic sketch by Internet comedian WelvenDaGreat in early 2015.

It's not as widely used these days, but I imagine you'll still hear it in schoolyard jokes.

I don't know if "these nuts on your chin" (the whole phrase) was the comedians' own creation, or a well-known punchline like "deez nuts", but I can imagine that the idea would be universally understood for immature comedic purposes, or humiliation. Indeed, a contemporary example is *tea-bagging* in video games (squatting your character over a defeated opponent's face).

Comment: Thank you for the "additional" info. I am sorry I can't distinguish if yours is correct or Lambie's. But if it is yours, it would be truly offensive though. (Can't distinguish too).

Comment: Still....if you watch the sketch until the end, the punchline becomes clearer. But +1 for the meme "deez [these] nuts" that was were my first thought was drawn to.

Comment: Yes, nuts is testicles but if they are (still) on his chin, how would that work? Nuts on your chin works because of something like moles on your skin..Moles grow on skin and here nuts (I guess slang for bollocks) are growing on a chin.

Answer (score 4):

These nuts are a old, tired, bad joke referring to a euphemism for male reproductive organs (testicles). And, your chin is your chin.

The gist of this bit of tawdry humor is to imply you are performing an act of oral copulation of such voraciousness and cavernous capacity that the gonads of the recipient of the fruits of your labor are being supported by the mandibular area of the site of the aforementioned job.

You are welcome...

to rest these nuts on your chin.

Comment: I don't know if the "Vince" actor and another are cheap characters. Vince, acted by Jordan Peele, his movie was nominated for 4 awards in 2017. link [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Out ]. But thanks.

Comment: @Kentaro - I wrote this at midnight in my time zone. I meant to say bawdy. Spellcheck must have changed it to tawdry and I did not catch it. Or, I was too tired (much like deez nuts jokes) and typed the wrong thing. Although “tawdry” would also be apropos since this joke was such a cheapshot at satire. Keegan-Michael Key and Jordan Peele don’t hit comedy gold on every outing. Sometimes they will settle for a sardonic smirk instead belly-busting guffaw.

Comment: Yes, nuts is balls, but your interpretation doesn't work so well, because presumably one actor is actually seeing nuts on the other's chin.

Comment: @Lambie - LOL! Well, that would not be comedy. The Peele character is not seeing nuts on anyone’s chin. “Deez nuts” was a popular diss in the 1990s. No one was actually exposing one’s genitalia. But, the implication was that the recipient of the verbal jab had the speaker’s nuts on their chin. American young men would sometimes use this as a good-natured insult or ribbing amongst their friends and colleagues. The skit is about a man too old, too important, and too well established to still be using such banter. Especially in the most inappropriate situations.

Comment: @Kentaro Tawdry humor is what a lot of comedy in the US is all about. It  has its place in American society....

Comment: @Lambie - Not just the US. Bad jokes are universally funny when done well. Benny Hill, Peter Sellers, and the Monty Python troupe are still considered masters. And, sexual situations and bodily emissions Like farts will never cease to be funny. After all, a cheap laugh is still a laugh.

Comment: He is seeing nuts there, so to speak. I was worried about these nuts on your chin.In other words, fellatio with a male.////Yes,right, Dean. But the Academy Awards tend to reward American "stuff" more than say, British stuff. I was just responding to that...

Comment: @Lambie - I’m not following you. Although the Americans, Brits, and the rest of the world might differ on humor, this skit was definitely not an Oscar winning effort. However Peele’s movies “Get Out” and “blacKkKlansman” we’re deserving of that and BAFTA consideration. Neither of which were his normal comedy. The “nuts” skit was more of what the brits would call “taking the piss” way too often for comedic effect.

Comment: "I don't know if the "Vince" actor and another are cheap characters. Vince, acted by Jordan Peele, his movie was nominated for 4 awards in 2017" **I was responding to that comment**

Comment: This is the only correct answer in this thread. Key & Peele are making fun of a simple fellatio joke, no doubt about it.

Answer (score -4):

There are **several jokes and puns** going on here.

- One is: to support life on [the Moon or Mars]. That kind of thing.

"How will we support life on Mars?

- A chin has been substituted for Mars or another planet.

The guy's chin has become a place that "supports" nuts; they grow there. **Nuts** like pecans and peanuts. A funny image.

So, the chin has been transformed into a place where nuts grow.

When Vince first says that, it's starts the whole,long image. It is just nonsense.

Also, there is a slight medical idea: *I was worried about those moles on your skin*, for example.

Moles becomes nuts and skin becomes chin.

EDIT: Yes, nuts are testicles and there is extended dialogue about it. Yes, as has been said below, it is partly a fellatio joke.

It's called comedy.

-

Comment: Huh, this is too difficult for ELLs. I think only the true native speakers are able to understand this. Thank you.

Comment: @Kentaro Yes, not an easy one for an ELLer. :) But you'll get there.

Comment: Did you actually watch the video? There is nothing in the answer that corresponds to the sketch. The punchline is at the end.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, and the nuts thing is repeated several times in several different ways.Yes, nuts means balls, but I really didn't think the dirty version works so well...

Comment: Sorry, no one in this sketch has real or imaginable nuts/balls/testicles on their chin. Is it some kind of joke?

Comment: @defaultlocale Here you say it isn't and below you say it is. Make up your mind.

Comment: This is a joke about someone using a pun about fellatio waaaaaaay too often. Period. The original nuts joke is about fellatio. The skit is about the Richard who uses the joke.

Comment: There is no pun at all. It's another technique.

Comment: @Lambie Unless otherwise I don't repeal the accept, you will get more likely to receive more downvotes. So I am sorry.

Comment: @Kentaro So remove it.